# How to convert RJ45 wiring to RJ25

Tags: networking, wiring, rj45

I have a RJ45 cable wiring. I need to use it to connect my printer to network. But the network socket that was available in my printer is RJ25 socket.

I thought that i can wired cross cable which is used an RJ45 on one side, and RJ25 on the other side, so I can connect my printer to my network.

Does anybody know how to to make a cross cable with RJ45 and RJ25??

Comment: Is the RJ25 connector on your printer an Ethernet port?

Comment: What model is your printer?

Comment: Likely this isn't ethernet port, but phone port for fax functions.